# Plot using one column from a table as the x-value, other columns as y-values Mathematica

Tags: excel, wolfram-mathematica

[image: table]

Say I have a table like this (but I will have way more y values). The first column (1-7) are the x values and the other three columns are the y-values; 8-14 and the first y-value sets, 15-21 the second, and so on.

I imported the table into mathematica, but I want assign the first column as x values and the others as separate y values as to plot them.

This link is similar to what I want to do, however they have a matrix instead of a table: [Plot using one column from a table as the x-value, other columns as y-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076801/plot-using-one-column-from-a-table-as-the-x-value-other-columns-as-y-values)

Answer (score 0):

I created a sheet in Excel with the same contents as you showed, exported that as an xlsx file, imported that into Mathematica, extracted columns 1 and 2, extracted columns 1 and 3, extracted columns 1 and 4 and plotted all of those in the same plot.

```
tbl = Import["Book2.xlsx"][[1]];
ListPlot[{tbl[[All, {1, 2}]], tbl[[All, {1, 3}]], tbl[[All, {1, 4}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will try this!

Comment: If I had 1800 y-values it would be tedious to code them all individually. How would I go about plotting all of them?